# Obtain the upper board in some cloud of nodes

Tags: python, linear-regression, curve-fitting

I have some cloud of nodes with increasing trend and some noise value. How to construct the trend line in Python that will be able to fit upper boundary of this distribution?
I want to obtain the line like in this example[image]